# Table extraction state of the art (beginning of 2018)

Tags: machine-learning

What is the current state of the art when it comes to extracting tabular data from documents (images/ocr, not pdf/html)?

I have come to ICDAR, but the last table detection challenges were from 2015.

Comment: It's not a hot problem so I doubt you'll find much specific new material, but you might find upgrades to the components (i.e., line detection). Welcome to the site!

Comment: There's a lot being done in [text detection](http://www.citeulike.org/user/mapto/tag/text_detection). If you have a good data set, it's worth taking one of the existing algorithms (most papers in the link also have git repositories with the code) and training it over your data, as tables on documents have specific features that would probably make the detection easier. Some of the listed algorithms are also [end-to-end](http://www.citeulike.org/user/mapto/tag/end-to-end_network) thus also doing the text recognition step.